# ArrayList<String> size not persisting between server and client

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I'm writing a server/client chat application in Java. In order to receive messages and then print the total dialog of the conversation, I add each message from the client to an ArrayList of Strings, and then send the whole ArrayList back to the client, to print out as the entire conversation.

My problem is that even though I am constantly adding elements to the ArrayList in the server, whenever I send it to the client, the size does not change, and only the first element is stored.

Server Program:

```
public class ArrayListServer {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = 8000;
    String me = "Server: ";
    ArrayList<String> convo = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
      ServerSocket server    = new ServerSocket(port);
      System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
      Socket client          = server.accept();
      System.out.println("Established connection.");
      ObjectInputStream  in  = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
      ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
      int i = 0;
      // receive messages from client
      while (true) {
        String msgFromClient = (String)in.readObject();
        convo.add(msgFromClient);
        System.out.println(me + "size: " + convo.size());
        out.writeObject(convo);
      }
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
      System.out.println("IOException occurred.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
      System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException occurred.");
    }

  }

}
```

Client Program:

```
public class ArrayListClient {

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = 8000;
    String me = "Client: ";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> convo = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
      Socket client = new Socket("localhost", port);
      ObjectOutputStream toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
      ObjectInputStream fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
      while (true) {
        System.out.print("> ");
        String msg = input.nextLine().trim();
        toServer.writeObject(msg);
        convo = (ArrayList<String>)fromServer.readObject();
        System.out.println(me + "size: " + convo.size());
      }
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhex) {
      System.out.println("UnknownHostException occurred.");
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
      System.out.println("IOException occurred.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
      System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException occurred.");
    }
  }

}
```

When I run the server and client, my output is:

```
> hi
Client: size: 1
> hi
Client: size: 1
> hi
Client: size: 1
> hi
Client: size: 1
> hi
Client: size: 1
> hi
Client: size: 1
> 

Server: Waiting for connection...
Server: Established connection.
Server: size: 1
Server: size: 2
Server: size: 3
Server: size: 4
Server: size: 5
Server: size: 6
```

I know the `ArrayList<>` and `String` class are both serializable, so I have no clue why this isn't working. I think it may be something to do with my Input/Output streams, but when I declared them local to the while loop and closed them at the end of it, my program would throw an IOException and halt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because on the client side you keep resetting the list and on the server side you are adding items to it.

Comment: @DevZer0 Which should be fine, he/she is expecting the *entire* ArrayList to be written to the output stream. So why does this not appear to be the case?

Comment: @user2864740 what do you mean by "stale code"?

Comment: @user2864740 Oh, no. These two classes are in their own package. I'm also having this problem with another client/server application.

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem but I do notice that you are not flushing the output streams after you write to them. You might want to add an out.flush() after out.writeObject() where out is both out and serverOut. You need it on both sides.

Comment: @user1888440 Didn't work, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. You use the same ObjectOutput and ObjectInput instances. ObjectOutput tries to not rewrite instances it has seen before. So the first time the server writes the convo array list it keeps a reference to it. When you add to it the reference does not change even though the contents of the list do. If you make the one line change below in your server this will prove to you that this is the problem:

```
out.writeObject( new ArrayList( convo ) );
```

The above is not a great solution because the ObjectOutputStream's reference map will keep growing one very iteration. But it will show you what the problem is so you can create a better solution.

The better solution is to just move the getInputStream and getOutputStream lines within the loop on both sides.

Also in case it's not obvious the strings work because on each iteration they are a different object reference. The List does not because on the server side you write the same reference each time even though it changes.

Comment: Brilliant! With this information I'm sure I can work out a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Great, i tried to solve this issue several Days..thanks!

You can use the reset() method to 'forgot' known references as shown below:

```
out.writeObject(object);
out.reset();    
out.flush();
```